# MVC Net Core Identity users not using EF not SQL

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want to create a Site using MVC .net core 3.0 and I'd like to use Identity but I need the users to be save not in SQL but in a service we already have for administering users, and I can query using a Rest Service.

What I need is when an user logins, instead of reading from EF and SQL I need to go to this other Service and check there if the user and password are correct.

I want to keep protecting the rest of the pages using the [Authorize] attribute once an user logs in.

Is there a way to change this behavior in .net core Identity?,

Thanks for any comments!

Comment: You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.1#aspnet-core-identity-stores-data-types) to implement a customized storage provider for ASP.NET Core Identity.

Comment: Thanks !!!! I found the info !